# Words combining together

Tags: java

Why is my code combining the old word with the new word? Input is "banana" output "banana" new input "dog" output "bananadgo"?

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word, afc, newWord;
    String s="";

    do
    {
        word=keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
        int i =word.length()-1;
        char firstLetter=word.charAt(0);
        afc=word.substring(1);
        newWord= afc+firstLetter;

        for( ; i>=0 ; )
        {
            s += newWord.charAt(i--);
        } 
        System.out.println(word + "," + s);

        if (s.equals(word))
            System.out.println("Words are equal.");
        else
            System.out.println("Words are not equal.");
    }
    while (!(word.equals("quit")));

}
```

Comment: what is it that you want your code to do?

Comment: separate the new input. Every time you enter a new word it combines the new word with the old word.

Comment: I am asking about the purpose of your code. Could you elaborate on what your code is supposed to do?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve???

Comment: I want my code to input a word such as "banana" take the first letter and put it at the end of the word "ananab" then spell the new word in reverse to "banana". if it was "dog" it would be "dgo". i want it to compare if the old and new word is equal to each other.

Comment: As a side note: If such code is used heavily, you should implement it with `Appendable`s such as `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` instead of 'String arithmetic' for more efficient concatenation. See: http://kaioa.com/node/59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not clearing the `s` variable at the beginning of the loop.

Should be

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word, afc, newWord;    

    do
    {
        String s=""; 
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word, afc, newWord;
    String s="";

    do
    {
        s = "";
        word=keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
        int i =word.length()-1;
        char firstLetter=word.charAt(0);
        afc=word.substring(1);
        newWord= afc+firstLetter;

        for( ; i>=0 ; )
        {
            s += newWord.charAt(i--);
        } 
        System.out.println(word + "," + s);

        if (s.equals(word))
            System.out.println("Words are equal.");
        else
            System.out.println("Words are not equal.");
    }
    while (!(word.equals("quit")));

}
```

Comment: doesn't work. that code just make the word "dog" to "ogd". its suppose to to be "dog" to "dgo".